# Mocking Knex queries with Sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, knex.js

I am looking to create unit tests to test my code. I would like to mock the response from knex code like the following

```
async function getDataById({ id }) {
return knex
    .from('data')
    .select(
        'a AS A',
        'b as B',
    )
    .where('id', id);}
```

I recently changed to used Knex so before this my test was

```
describe('Data Get', () => {
let dBStub;
before(() => {
    dBStub = sinon.stub(conn, 'executeQuery');
    dBStub.withArgs(sinon.match.string, validId).returns(data);
});

after(() => {
    conn.executeQuery.restore();
});

it('Should provide prices for valid ID', () =>
    pricesDb
        .get({ id: validId })
        .should.eventually.deep.equal({ data: expected }));
```

I no longer have the execute query methods and just have a knex file.

How do I convert the tests to provide mock the response from the `getDataById` function?

When I convert the stub to the `getDataByID` method I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property

Comment: Shouldn't you stub the property `executeQuery` of the object `dbConnection` instead of `conn` ?

Comment: That was my mistake, I modified the question. But this is the old unit tests I had before I made the move to knex. The query is executed by knex in the first code block now.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the unit test for testing `getDataById` function:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { knex } from "./db";

export async function getDataById({ id }) {
  return knex
    .from("data")
    .select("a AS A", "b as B")
    .where("id", id);
}
```

`db.ts`:

```js
import Knex from "knex";

export const knex = Knex({
  client: "pg",
  connection: {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "your_database_user",
    password: "your_database_password",
    database: "myapp_test"
  }
});
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { getDataById } from "./";
import sinon from "sinon";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { knex } from "./db";

describe("getDataById", () => {
  it("should mock response", async () => {
    const mResponse = { id: 1 };
    const selectStub = sinon.stub().returnsThis();
    const whereStub = sinon.stub().resolves(mResponse);
    sinon.stub(knex, "from").callsFake((): any => {
      return {
        select: selectStub,
        where: whereStub
      };
    });
    const actual = await getDataById({ id: 1 });
    expect(actual).to.be.deep.eq(mResponse);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  getDataById
    ✓ should mock response


  1 passing (45ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 db.ts         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/50482860